# Generic class in Android package and manifest

Tags: android, manifest

I want to have a normal class file in my android package that is not a component but will be used by an activity. Is this allowed? How do I add this in the manifest if required?

Right now it is not part of my manifest and I am getting an 'INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED' error in my Android project and don't know if it's because of this generic class file.

Thanks

Comment: I think you should clarify that a bit. What is a 'normal class file' - you mean literally a .class file compiled by a Java compiler? The error you're getting is likely unrelated so trimming it down to the bare basics and attaching could be a good idea. And if you are worried about generics -- you can use Java5-compatible generics in your Android code just fine.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this allowed?

Yes.

> How do I add this in the manifest if required?

You don't put it in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

It's not needed to add to the manifest. You can have as many "normal classes" as you wish (by normal i suppose that are classes that do not extend activity).

Take a lot at LogCat during install to check what the problem is.

Comment: There are a lot of 'WifiManager ShowApDialog' and 'StatusBarPolicy' errors in LogCat. Coudld this be a permissions related thing?

Comment: I actually tried editing my post and put the dump in there. But it never seems to have come out of peer review :) I later found the issue to actually be due a malformed xml. I am however stuck at another point now and not able to figure where a Null pointer exception is coming from inside the API. Will post separately for this. Thanks all.